# Pass Static value to dynamic Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I am sure this is a simple question but have not been able to figure this out.  The below shows a function that is created and added to a google map marker on the `mousedown` event.  This is created for each marker iterated through.

The part eluding me is on line 5 below the `pickupVenue(data[i].id)` the value submitted in this function call is always the last iterated value.  I want to stick a static value there of what I am iterating through when creating each marker.

```
for (i in data) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mousedown', function() {
        state = PINCH;
        map.setOptions({draggable: false});
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function() { pickupVenue(data[i].id) }, 1000); 
    });
}
```

---- working result ----

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mousedown', pickupMarker(data[i].Listing.id));

function pickupMarker(id) {
    return function() {
        state = PINCH;
        map.setOptions({draggable: false});
        timeoutId = setTimeout('pickupVenue('+id+')', 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: @duante - I know you've already pick an answer, but I hope you can take a look at my new answer below as it's an alternate way of doing this with a utility function that makes timers easier to use in these situations.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I appreciate your answer and will probably use that for something but patricks was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the function you pass as the event listener has a variable in its scope that references the value that `i` held in the loop without being modified `i` being modified.

Currently all the functions you're creating in the loop are sharing the same `i` variable, so they'll all end up getting whatever value `i` references when the handler is finally invoked.

In JavaScript, the only way to create a new variable scope is to invoke a function, and create a local variable (or parameter) in that function that references the value you want.

Like this:

```
function createListener( i ) {
    return function() {
        state = PINCH;
        map.setOptions({draggable: false});
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function() { pickupVenue(data[i].id) }, 1000); 
    };
}

for (i in data) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mousedown', createListener( i ) );
}
```

Here I created a `createListener()` function, and passed `i` into it.

Because your listener function is now being created inside the `createListener()` function, that listener will reference the `i` in that variable scope, which will continue to retain whatever value it was given when you invoked `createListener()` (unless your function modifies `i`).

Then `createListener()` *returns* that listener function, which is passed as the third argument to `addListener()`.

Comment: thx really like ur createListener method... since i need to reuse it in many places will make it easy  http://jsfiddle.net/D2Etw/6/

Comment: @IAbstract: Nah, just wait for one of those many occasions where I'm completely wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

Enhanced version from IAbstractDownvoteFactor's Closure answer:

```
for (i in data) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mousedown', function() {
        state = PINCH;
        map.setOptions({draggable: false});

        var timeoutFn = function(theId) {
            return function realTimeoutFn() {
                pickupVenue(theId); // value of "theId" is kept
            };
        };

        timeoutId = setTimeout(timeoutFn(data[i].id), 1000); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this question with `setTimeout()` come up so often and it's always messy to remember the right closure syntax so I thought that maybe we should just create a `setTimeoutWithData()` utility function that makes this really easy.  So here it is:

```
function setTimeoutWithData(rock, fn, t, ctx) {
    ctx = ctx || window;
    function localFn() {
        fn.call(ctx, rock);
    }
    return(setTimeout(localFn, t));
}
```

It takes four parameters and returns the timerID:

```
rock
```

This is any piece of data of any type that will be passed through to your callback.  If you want to pass lots of data, you can make rock be an object or an array.

```
fn
```

This is your callback function.  It will be passed the rock as it's parameter so your callback should be declared like this:  `function fn(rock) {}`

```
t
```

This is the setTimeout time value in ms, same as setTimeout.

```
ctx
```

This is the only optional parameter.  If you want your callback to have a particular `this` value, you can configure that with the ctx parameter.  Among other things, this allows you to use a setTimeoutWithData to call a method on an object and have `this` set appropriately so it works more easily with object oriented programming.  If ctx is not passed, then `this` will be set to `window` (same as setTimeout does).

So, the problem in the original question here would be solved like this:

```
for (i in data) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mousedown', function() {
        state = PINCH;
        map.setOptions({draggable: false});
        timeoutId = setTimeoutWithData(data[i].id, function(anID) { pickupVenue(anID) }, 1000); 
    });
}
```

And, here's a sample app showing this utility function in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3SUAJ/.